# Node.js app not starting after upgrading webpack to v5

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-5

I've upgraded all npm libraries to latest versions including webpack..
Made appropriate updates to webpack.config file...

But my app fails to start with an error I cannot find solution for even google it:

```
[1650242490129] ERROR (xxxxxxxxxxxx): Cannot add property autodllStatsRetrieved, object is not extensible
    err: {
      "type": "TypeError",
      "message": "Cannot add property autodllStatsRetrieved, object is not extensible",
      "stack":
```

Please, advise

Comment: are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/autodll-webpack-plugin ?

Comment: yes, I am.. And I did all appropriate updates to webpack.config related to latest version of AutoDll..

Comment: so, did you read the "Important Note" ... seems you should not be using it for webpack 5 as it is **obsolete** - i.e. did you remove `autodll-webpack-plugin`

Comment: that fixed the issue.. Thank you Bravo!